# How do I stop and restart the accompanying dlls of a service on windows systems?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, dll

I am trying to build a script using PowerShell to suppress alerts from Systems (Windows Server) monitored by Webhobbit. The Webhobbit is getting system statistics (CPU/Memory in Use/uptime etc.) from an application called BBwin.
BBwin reports these statistics using dll files it has built-in.

For Unix servers, I was able to suppress the alert by just disabling the running dlls using a bash script. But, I'm unable to do so using Powershell on a Windows Server. I have tried using regsrv32.exe in my script, it is not working. Using PowerShell I was able to just stop the BBWin service, but not each dlls loaded

**My question is: How do I stop and restart the accompanying dlls of a service on windows systems?**

Below are the scripts I have built to suppress the alerts:

**Bash Script**

```
 #!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
   echo "USAGE:  $2 time 'message'"
   echo "Where"
   echo "   time = maintenance time [in minutes]"
   echo "   message = 'quoted downtime message' [enclosed in single-quotes]"
   exit
fi

time=$1
message=$2

# List of hosts to disable
hosts='ABCD'
tests='msgs procs url'

for test in $tests; do

   for host in $hosts; do
      echo "Disabling $host.$test"
      /usr/local/hobbit/client/bin/bb webhobbit "disable $host.$test $time $message"
   done
done
```

**PowerShell Script**

```
   $services = 'BBwin'
   $servers  = 'ABCD'
   $problems = @()

   foreach($server in $servers){
   foreach($service in $services){


   # Checking the current status of the BBwin
   $service_status = (Get-Service -Name $service).status

   #If Service Status Is : Running
   if(($service_status -eq 'running')){

        Stop-Service -Name $service 

        # Try to stop it and wait 5 seconds
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5


        #How do I get access to msgs procs url?



        # Check again if it is running now, if not add info to $problems
        if((((Get-Service -Name $service).status) -eq 'stopped')){
          Write-Host "Process stopped succesfully"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: From a Windows perspective, the question does not make sense. One does not start or stop a dll but rather a service or a process.

Comment: By definition a DLL is a library that is utilized by a service or program. You do not stop and restart DLL's. They are simply libraries of code added to and utilized by the underlying program. They are inactive until called upon by code in the executed program.

Comment: Okay. But Is there a way I can make them inactive so that the executing program is unable to call them?

Comment: This `/usr/local/hobbit/client/bin/bb webhobbit "disable $host.$test $time $message"` doesn't *disable dll's*, it just starts webhobbit and tells it to disable certain messages from the looks of it. A powershell alternative could be `& webhobbit "disable $host.$test $time $message"`

Comment: Yes, you are correct @LievenKeersmaekers, it only disables the reporting of its status to WebHobbit.